# If else returning true value, when the value is actually false

Tags: javascript

I am making a program that asks the user for 2 numbers ( a and b). Then the program asks them if they want to add, subtract, multiply, or divide, by inputting the number 1 for addition, 2 for subtract, 3 for multiply, and 4 for division. If any other number other than 1-4 is inputted ( say 0) the program must stop, and an alert tells them to re try the calculation. if the user inputted the first 3 numbers correctly, then they should get their computation in an alert box (THIS IS NOT WORKING!).

Then they are asked with a prompt box if they wish to do another computation ( y to continue, anything else ends the program), the prompt shows, but if i input anything the program continues. there is an If else statement within the cont1() function which is called when the user inputs a number corresponding to the arithmetic he/she wishes to complete.

Currently I have no console errors, my first 3 prompt boxes from my getValues() function works properly, but the arithmetic of the add(), subtract, etc functions are not working properly, the alert window never pops up with the answer.

---

**HERE IS MY CODE!(EDITED 3/10/16 10:31)
EDIT: MY if else statement is working now.. But the arithmetic is still not working.** 
 **10:31 EDIT:    The arithmetic portion is now fixed because i didn't have the parseInt(), but the cont1() function is still executing as true when the input by the user is suppose to stop the prorgam**

10:52 edit : With the getValues() function :  the function checks to see if a, b and c are numbers, when i input all numbers it returns that they are not numbers. Also got rid of the arithmetic functions, converted them over to a switch statement.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<title> B_Math Calculator </title>

<head>
<script> 

function getValues()
{

 var a = parseInt(prompt("please enter the first number"), 1);
 var b = parseInt(prompt("please enter the second number"), 2);
 var c = parseInt(prompt("please enter 1 to : ADD , 2 to : SUBTRACT, 3 to : MULTIPLY, or 4 to : DIVIDE"), 1);

 if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) || isNaN(c)){
   alert("One or more of your inputs were not numeric!");
 }

 alert("Answer is: " + calc(a,b,c));
 cont1();
}

function calc(oper1, oper2, oper3){
  switch (oper3){
     case 1:
        return oper1 + oper2;
        break;
     case 2:
        return oper1 - oper2;
        break;
     case 3:
       return oper1 * oper2;
        break;
     case 4:
       return oper1 / oper2;
        break;
     default:
      alert("please enter 1 to : ADD , 2 to : SUBTRACT, 3 to : MULTIPLY, or 4 to : DIVIDE, press  Click here to do some math!, to try  again.");
      break;
  }
}

// ASK IF USER IS DONE (Y FOR YES , ANYTHING ELSE FOR NO)
function cont1()
{
  var answ = prompt("Next computation? Y : yes, any other letter  for no.");
  if(answ.toLowerCase() === "y") {
    getValues();
  } else {
    alert("thank you for using my calculator!");
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="getValues()" value="Call Function"> Click here to do some math! </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `else if (c!=1,2,3,4)` - if does not work like that!

Comment: First you have to be aware the prompts will return a String not a number, so you will need to convert it into a number like parseInt(a) and parseInt(b). Second, once you return from a function, all code after that won't be executed. So, if you want to alert the add fuction, you can do something like alert(add(a,b));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way to accomplish what you want:

```
if(c==1) {
    add(a,b);
} else if(c==2) {
    subtract(a,b);
} else if(c==3) {
    multiply(a,b);
} else if(c==4) {
    divide(a,b);
} else {
    alert("please enter 1 to : ADD , 2 to : SUBTRACT, 3 to : MULTIPLY, or 4 to : DIVIDE, press  Click here to do some math!, to try  again.");
}
```

Or, better yet:

```
switch (c){
   case 1:
      add(a,b);
      break;
   case 2:
      subtract(a,b);
      break;
   case 3:
      multiply(a,b);
      break;
   case 4:
      divide(a,b);
      break;
   default:
    alert("please enter 1 to : ADD , 2 to : SUBTRACT, 3 to : MULTIPLY, or 4 to : DIVIDE, press  Click here to do some math!, to try  again.");
    break;
}
```

Which is a much cleaner way to structure an if/else that only takes a single expression into account.

In either case, proper indentation makes the code much more readable.

You also have problems with the location of your `return` statements in that you have more code that comes after them. A `return` statement doesn't just return a value to the caller, but it also returns programmatic control to the caller, meaning that your function ENDS when it encounters `return`.  So, in your case, no code that comes after the return will be processed.

Additionally, in your `cont1()` function, your test is:

```
 if(answ = "y")
```

This is not testing `answ` to see if it has a value of "`y`", the single equal sign is assigning the value of "`y`" to `answ`, which is an operation that evaluates to `true`, meaning that you will always execute the code in the true branch. You need to use double (`==`) or triple (`===` for equality without conversion) to compare values.

As I've mentioned, proper code formatting is important, not only for readability, but for processing. Opening curly braces should appear at the end of the line for which they belong. This:

```
 function foo()
 {
```

and this:

```
 if(condition)
 {
     true code
 }
 else if (condition)
 {
```

Should be:

```
 function foo() {
```

and this:

```
 if(condition) {
     true code
 } else if (condition) {
```

As a side note, your code assumes that the user input will be numeric, which is wrong for two reasons.

1. A prompt ALWAYS returns a string, regardless of the input.
2. The user might (will) type something unexpected, like "one"

Before operating on the input, you should check it. There are many techniques for determining if input is numeric (many have pros and cons), but something along the lines of the following would be appropriate:

```
 var a = parseInt(prompt("please enter the first number"),10);
 var b = parseInt(prompt("please enter the second number"),10);
 var c = parseInt(prompt("please enter 1 to : ADD , 2 to : SUBTRACT, 3 to : MULTIPLY, or 4 to : DIVIDE"),10);

 if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) || isNaN(c)){
   alert("One or more of your inputs were not numeric!");
 }
```

Lastly, instead of having 4 separate functions that largely do the same thing and decide which one to call with an `if` or `switch`, why not just have one function that decides what math to do based on an input parameter.

See this fiddle for a complete solution that incorporates all these points, using `switch`:  https://jsfiddle.net/m0r5r4dx/17/

Comment: I tried both of your methods, the switch statement always returns any value as false (even if i put in 1,2,3,4), the if else you have given me works fine, but after i input a number (1,2,3,4) it fails to continue to the corresponding function, for example i input 1 for the first number, 2 for the second, and 1 for the third( i want to add them), and the cont1() function isn't executing now.. my new code is with the edited question.

Comment: @Alex Bitar Your return statements must be the last thing in their respective code blocks.

Comment: i put the return at the end of the functions, they all work properly now! i also added that bit of code you recommended. The last problem i have is the cont1() function to stop when anything but y is inputed

Comment: @AlexBitar See my last edited post for the reason that is happening and the solution.

Comment: I'm still amazed by the down voters who will down vote without a comment, particularly when the answer is clear, correct and detailed.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> (c!=1,2,3,4)
> ```

The comma operator returns whatever is on the right hand side, so this evaluates as:

```
(false,2,3,4)
```

which evaluates as:

```
4
```

---

Use an array if you want to tell if a value isn't in a set.

```
if ( -1 == [1, 2, 3, 4].indexOf(c) )
```

Comment: But the OP doesn't just need to know if c is in the array. They need to know exactly what value c is, so the correct function is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

```
else if (c!=1,2,3,4)
```

This isn't doing what you think it's doing. What this is doing is:

1. Checking if `c` isn't equal to `1`.
2. Checking if `2` is *truthy* (which it is).
3. Checking if `3` is *truthy* (which it is).
4. Checking if `4` is *truthy* (which it is).

Due to the commas, the value returned is actually `4` (meaning the `if` statement ignores the first 3 anyway).

What you need to do is change this `else` clause to:

```
if (c != 1 && c != 2 && c != 3 && c != 4)
```

Or:

```
if (c < 1 || c > 4)
```

I suggest you take a look at [MDN's notes on `if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) before doing anything else.

Comment: Or just remove the `if` altogether  ... all the cases are already handled in the preceding `if` clauses, the `else` suffices in this case.

Comment: No truthiness tests actually take place for `c!=1`, `2` and `3` -- they're just evaluated, then dropped on the floor. Only the last expression (`4`) is tested for truthiness.

Comment: I just removed the last if all together, not sure why i didn't realize that last if wasn't needed lol thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have mentioned, your method of checking if c is 1, 2, 3, or 4 is incorrect, but you don't actually need your last `else if` to be an `else if`, as by the time you've reached it you already know that `c` is not 1, 2, 3, or 4. You could replace it with an `else`, and it should work.

Also, your various functions have code after the `return` that will never execute, as the function finishes as soon as it reaches a `return`. Since you aren't actually doing anything with the value you return, you should probably remove the `return` statements.